# Swift 3 Script - Access process arguments

Tags: swift, shell, command-line, swift3

We have a script written in Swift lang. Now we updated to Swift 3 and facing the next issue:
We can not access process arguments, compile error here:

error: instance member 'arguments' cannot be used on type 'Process'

How should we access process arguments now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the same time found a solution.
For reference (since Swift 3.0 August 4 snapshot):
Process was just renamed into CommandLine.